# jsf validation for datatable

Tags: jsf-2, datatable

I want to validate the below datatable only if user doesn't enter any values in the given p:inputText field

```
<p:dataTable id="depositDataTable" value="#{pc_intimationDeposit.pendingRep.depositeBeans}" var="deposit">
    <p:column style="text-align:right">
        <h:outputText value="#{deposit.depParticulars}" />
    </p:column>
   <p:column id="value">
        <h:inputText id="depositDetails" class="right_input" value="#{deposit.amnt}" tabindex="2"                                       converterMessage="Please Enter Numbner's Only" validatorMessage="please"> 
           <f:convertNumber  pattern="##,####,##0.00" for="depositDetails" type="currency" />
        </h:inputText>
<p:message id="errMsgDepositDetails" for="depositDetails" display="text"></p:message>   
    </p:column>
</p:dataTable>
```

pc_intimationDeposit.pendingRep.depositeBeans----> is a list(size 3) of depositBeans

i have used f:convertNumber for the entered values are correct to our requirements

but if user doesn't enter A SINGLE VALUE then i need validate for null check
i.e., user has to enter any one field

and i need to display the error message on top of the datatable used

please help me
Thank in you advance

Answer (score 1):

- If you want to have every depositDetail [inputs](http://www.jsftoolbox.com/documentation/help/12-TagReference/html/h_inputText.html) populated, mark
  them with `required=true`.
- If you only want to have one of them filled, on your action method,
  iterate over your model to ensure there's at least one not empty (**you shouldn't have null values here**):

  ```
  boolean filled = false;
  for (DepositeBean dep : depositeBeans){
  if (!dep.getAmnt.equals("")){
      filled = true;
  }
  }
  if (!filled){
     FacesContext.getCurrentInstance().addMessage(null, 
       new FacesMessage(FacesMessage.SEVERITY_ERROR, "You have to fill at least one deposit detail field", null));
  }
  ```

For messages to be displayed, add an [`h:message`](http://www.jsftoolbox.com/documentation/help/12-TagReference/html/h_message.html) tag and point it to your table:

`<h:message for="depositDataTable" style="color:red" />`

Comment: can't do the same using jsf validation i.e., implementing validator...      public void validate(FacesContext fc, UIComponent comp, Object value)

Comment: As the method signature says, here you have the issue that you're receiving a single component into your validator. So each input does not know about the other ones. That way you should create your own `depositDataTable` custom component and write the same logic I suggest above, in order to be able to validate the whole datatable.